# Fast multithreaded list with many reads

Tags: c#, .net

I want to keep a list of threads which all have an unique guid. I have to check lots of times if the guid exists in the dictionary, if not create the Thread. The thread itself will check if it has to destroy itself and remove the guid from the list.

But starting and stopping a thread is very rare: 1 in 10.000.000 reads, so I need a concurrent list that can peek quickly if the Guid is in there.

I can use the `ConcurrentBag` but it's unsorted not good for just peeking. I can use the `ConcurrentDictionary` but it's a dictionary, and I don't need to store values.

Is my best option to use a `ReaderWriterLock` on a `HashSet`?

Comment: I would recommend you the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (well, Microsoft recommends it over the other)

Comment: How about using the dictionary with a dummy value?

Comment: Your create/destroy pattern sounds like a race-condition even if the dictionary is threadsafe. Be careful.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I was thinking about that, but I can't image it can be faster than a thread safe list. The create/destroy is VERY slow, we are talking about hours before a thread is destroyed or created.

Comment: If you're not using a dictionary, how are you associating a Guid to a thread?  If you're just talking about a set of Guids you just need to protect access to the collection (set, list, array, whatever)--which is exactly what `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is for...